# Do I need to install Dr Racket(scheme) run scheme executable

Tags: executable, racket

I have Dr Racket install on one machine. I wrote a scheme program and created an executable(test.tgz).  I want this executable to be executed on other machine where Dr Racket is not install. When I unzip this file the folder structure is

```
test
-bin
  -executable
-lib
 -.....
```

when I try to run the executable it complains that the lib does not exists?

Am I missing something? Anyone created executable with Dr. Racket before?

Comment: I created one but indeed I had DrRacket installed. Maybe you DO need to install racket packages. OR Maybe is something wrong in your code.